# Does Wifi access points have an ip address?

Tags: android, wifi

I am trying to make an application which can connect from a mobile to a wifi controller. Planning to do a socket connection(multicast) ... The only values that i am able to get through the wifi android apis are SSID and BSSID.. Can anyone tell me if i am supposed to proceed with these values or am i supposed to connect with an IP address ? If i am supposed to connect with BSSID.. how do i go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wifi access points need not have an IP address, any more than wired switches and hubs do.  However a large number do, as they also act on the IP layer as DHCP servers and network gateways.

What exactly are you trying to do?  It sounds likely that it is not the Wifi access point proper that you need to talk to.

If it supports TCP and UDP, it will of course have an IP address.  This will not be directly discoverable from the Wifi APIs, and you'll need some other means of discovering that.  It's hard to say what exactly will be a reasonable method to do this without knowing what the AP is, and what services it provides.

Common ways of enumerating services provided on a network include [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol); [multicast DNS](http://www.multicastdns.org/)/[DNS service discovery](http://dns-sd.org/) which is used by "[Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29)" and "[Zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf)"), [SSDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) and [uPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play), and of course static configuration.

I'm not familiar enough with the Android network APIs to recommend anything, though http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/ appears to be a usable Java multicast DNS library.

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the response.. I am trying to build an application which can connect to a hardware that i am planning to buy from another vendor which will have a UART-WIFI module which will support  RAW / UDP / TCP format of network data transmission,it will have its own MAC...etc. I would like to have some inputs on how to go about it...