# Can I get the IP address of the access point to I am connected to over wifi?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

Hi I am new to android programming. I am basically trying to connect to an access point and send it come commands. After connecting to it over wifi, is it possible to programatically obtain it's IP address so that I can establish a http connection with it?
So far I know that we can obtain the device IP, but not sure if the access point IP can be obtained. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Wifi access points have an ip address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929438/does-wifi-access-points-have-an-ip-address)

Comment: It's not clear from that duplicate that what you're asking even makes sense.

Comment: @kabuko The access point I am referring to does have an IP address assigned. I can ping and connect to it. My question was if it was possible to obtain this IP from an android application. Also, the duplicate post does not answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String getApIpAddr(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcpInfo = wifiManager.getDhcpInfo();
    byte[] ipAddress = convert2Bytes(dhcpInfo.serverAddress);
    try {
        String apIpAddr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddress).getHostAddress();
        return apIpAddr;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static byte[] convert2Bytes(int hostAddress) {
    byte[] addressBytes = { (byte)(0xff & hostAddress),
            (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 8)),
            (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 16)),
            (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 24)) };
    return addressBytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the outside (public) IP address of the access point that the device is connected to.  If so, yes there is a simple way to get the public IP address of the access point that a device is connected to.  Simply setup a script on a web server that will echo back the IP address of any client that connects to it (similar to www.whatismyip.com).  Then, your device just needs to do a GET request to the script, and this will return the outside IP of the access point that the device is connected to.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately, I will not have access to any other web server. This needs to be a standalone android app that interacts just with the access point it is connected to. Also, by IP of access point, I meant the IP that is assigned to it by a DHCP agent using which the AP can be pinged.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to get the IP address

```
try {
           for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) 
               {
                    NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();       
                    for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses();enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) 
                      {
                        InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                        if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress())
                         { 
                         //My IP address
                               String Ip= inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();

                         }   
                       }
                  }

            }
     catch (SocketException e) 
     { 
       Log.e("Error occurred  ", e.toString());
      }
```

Comment: This is perfect code but i don't think that it will work for wifi

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. The above code returns an ipv6 address when connected to wifi. So I am not able to check if this is the right address. I also tried including if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && (inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address)), but again I don't get any IPv4 address. The AP i am connected to does have an IPv4 address, and I can ping it from within the subnet. But this is not returning the same.